# Builds with Visual Studio 2017 project but _MSC_VER shows 1900

Tags: visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, solution, vcxproj

I have a problem with a project and maybe someone could give me some hints. I have a project within a solution, which was created or updated the last time with `Visual Studio 2015`. Now, I want to build this project with `Visual Studio 2017`.

So, I start the batch file `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64` with parameter . Then, I upgrade the project with the command `devenv solution.sln /Upgrade`. I see the following output:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.27703.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Upgrading project 'project1'...
    Configuration 'Debug|Win32': changing Platform Toolset to 'v141' (was 'v140').
    Configuration 'Debug|x64': changing Platform Toolset to 'v141' (was 'v140').
    Configuration 'Release|Win32': changing Platform Toolset to 'v141' (was 'v140').
    Configuration 'Release|x64': changing Platform Toolset to 'v141' (was 'v140').

Migration completed successfully, but some warnings were detected during migration.
For more information, see the migration report:
C:\path\to\project\UpgradeLog.htm
```

In this `UpgradeLog.htm`, I only see this warning:

```
solution.sln: Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in released versions of Visual Studio newer than Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.
```

Then, when the project is built, I see this message when the project is built (I removed the real project name, the names of the source files and the real paths here. This shouldn't be a problem):

```
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /Iinclude /IC:\path\to\other\include /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /O2 /Ob2 /Ot /Oy- /GL /D WIN64 /D NDEBUG /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Release\x64\\" /Fd"C:\path\to\debug\symbols\debug.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue c1.cpp c2.cpp c3.cpp
  c1.cpp
  c2.cpp
  c3.cpp
  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
Lib:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\Lib.exe /OUT:"C:\path\to\lib\project.lib" some_other.lib /LIBPATH:C:\path\to\other\lib64 /NOLOGO /MACHINE:X64 /LTCG Release\x64\c1.obj
  Release\x64\c2.obj
  Release\x64\c3.obj
```

But later, when I search in the file `project.lib` for `_MSC_VER` with the command `find "_MSC_VER" project.lib`, I get this output (several times):

```
/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1900"
```

But I expected to get this output (because of building with `Visual Studio 2017`):

```
/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1910"
```

How this can be?

Comment: The /failifmismatch injected linker option is there to verify that you don't try to link any libraries that were built with an incompatible compiler version.  Focus on *incompatible*, both VS2015 and VS2017 use version 140 of the runtime dlls.  This does not have anything to do with the reason you need to edit c3.cpp

Answer (score 1):

`/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1900"` indicates the file was built with [MSVC++ 14.0 (Platform Toolset v140)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering). Since, according to the upgrade log, `project1` has been migrated to v141, I'd think that either:

- it has not been rebuilt and you're linking to old .obj files; or
- the messages you're seeing are from object files built by other
  projects which target v140.

Regarding the compile-time messages, I suspect you're using Boost libraries no later than 1.62 - you can see the version check and message at the bottom of the [visualc.hpp header](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp). If this is the case, you will need to either update your Boost libraries or change the Platform Toolset back to v140.